# Deploy Java maven project on ec2 instance

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Java maven project in Eclipse. I have set up an AWS EC2 instance. How do I deploy this project on the instance I have created. I have installed the AWS add on for Eclipse. It is an API, so I would like to deploy this so I can connect to the end points non-locally. I have been trying to figure out how to do this for weeks...

Comment: If you want a good answer, you need to provide more information. For example, is this a web API, running within a container such as Tomcat or Jetty? Is it a library that you can only call from Java code? Is it a TCP server running your own custom protocol? Or an RMI server? Or something completely different? The answer is going to be completely different for each of these.

Comment: @kdgregory apologies for the lack of info - I am a beginner. The project is web API using Jetty container in NetBeans, however I also have it in eclipse using tomcat. Basically the program scrapes certain websites every 10 mins and stores the data in a DB (SQLite). The API queries the database and returns JSON output. So ideally I would like this code to be running on the instances I have created (scraping every 10 mins) and to also have the API accessible. The front end uses the JSON info to create graphs.. apologies for my ignorance but I have no idea how to get what I have built online!

Comment: You need to learn about building a deployable [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)). Perhaps NetBeans or Eclipse will do this for you, but the normal approach is to use a tool such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Then you can deploy to AWS using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html).

Comment: The things that you need to learn are too broad for a Stack Overflow question. My recommendation is that you look for tutorials on the things that I've linked, and ask specific questions if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it's an API, you can use API Gateway for that purpose and expose the API as per your requirement.

Checkout: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html

Comment: Thanks. However I would also like to be able to have my Java code running on the instance. Basically the main method executes every 10 minutes which updates the DB.